# IBM Q jobs being cancelled without error or explanation?

Tags: ibm-q-experience

While sometimes the jobs run without any problem, and in other cases there are errors that can tell how to troubleshoot, in this case it seems there is no explanation from IBM.

Has anyone had similar problems? What is the solution?

The circuit is correct. It is not clear why the transpiling was "cancelled". This is not a one-time rare incidence. It is running fine on other devices.

[image]

Comment: No `Status Description`?

Comment: No, nothing at all.

Comment: Still happening.

Answer (score 1):

You can check out the error message in `https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/jobs/<job id>`:

[image: screenshot of a job in the IBM Quantum website]

With the IBM Quantum Qiskit provider, you can also do this:

```
from qiskit import IBMQ
provider = IBMQ.enable_account('<your token>')
backend = provider.get_backend('<backend name>')
job = backend.retrieve_job('<job id>')
job.error_message()
```

If you see now message, maybe it is time to ask in the `#ibm-quantum-systems` [slack channel](https://ibm.co/joinqiskitslack).

Comment: The status description does not exist for my case. It's simply not there. I also checked the error page, nothing there.

Comment: job.error_message() does not return anything.

Comment: In that case, ask on Slack.